# How to read Dynamically updating YAML with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, yaml

I have yaml file, looks like this.

```
---
env:
  credentials:
    endpoint: "value"
    username: "value"
    tenant: "value"
    password: "value"

  ld_a:
    network:
        subnet-name:
            - sub1
        ld_filename:
            - ld1.xml
        fd_filename:
            - fd1.xml
            - fd2.xml

  ld_b:
    network:
        subnet-name:
            - sub2
        ld_filename:
            - ld2.xml
        fd_filename:
            - fd1.xml
            - fd2.xml
```

At any point of time user can update the YAML with `ld_c` or subsequent tags or remove any tag.

As of now I am checking for `ld_a` in dict and handling nested key, values(as below).

```
with open(r'C:\file.yaml', 'r') as fd:
    data = yaml.load(fd)

items = data.get('env')
for descriptor, value in items.iteritems():
    if descriptor == 'credentials':
        tenant = value.get('tenant')
        username = value.get('username')
        password = value.get('password')
        endpoint = value.get('endpoint')


    if descriptor == 'ld_a':
        for descriptor in value.viewvalues():
            for user_networks in descriptor.get('subnet-name'):
                get_network_details(neutron, user_networks)
```

But when user would be adding / removing keys eg `ld_c` . How should we handle this in python.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that a user would add/remove keys by modifying the contents of file.yaml in the filesystem where the program is running. If there's a reason why the user can't just re-run the program each time he/she modifies the file then maybe you need to clarify your assumptions/requirements.

Comment: I dont get it. You could reload the file at intervals and check for new `keys` (for eg `ld_c`) and see if things are there to perform operations on it. I mean you just have to add more and more `if` statements to your code!

Comment: And another thing what do you mean by `subsequent tags`?? You mean `ld_c` , `ld_d` , `ld_e` and so on?

Comment: @Peter : Apologies. . I think my explanation was not accurate. let me rephrase it.! Requirement is user can add/remove tag `ld_c` and so.. in YAML and execute the code. however my problem is how should i know which key user has entered .

Comment: @TechJS : yes.. its `ld_c` and so on.. let me try out the answer you have posted.!

Comment: To be able to determine adding or removing of keys, you need to store the information on which keys you have somewhere between parsing of the file. You can do that in the YAML file, e.g. as the value of a top-level key which is a list of all the defined keys, but that involves the risk that a user will edit that information in your file as well (so you might want to save that list in a different file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With my basic knowledge here is your answer:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"ld_[a-z]")

if pattern.match(descriptor):
    for descriptor in value.viewvalues():
        for user_networks in descriptor.get('subnet-name'):
            get_network_details(neutron, user_networks)
```

Basically you are performing regular expressions on `descriptor` and it matches every `ld_` character followed by one character that is a to z (a, b, c ... etc.)